# What is the difference between # and . with CSS?

Tags: css

What is the difference between `#` and `.` with CSS?

```
#main
{
    background-color: #fff;
    _height: 1px; /* only IE6 applies CSS properties starting with an underscrore */
}


.main
 {
    background-color: #fff;
    _height: 1px; /* only IE6 applies CSS properties starting with an underscrore */
 }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

'**#**' represents an *id*. the '**.**' is a *class*.

So.. `<tagname id="main">` and `<tagname class="main">`....

hope that helps.

Answer (score 7):

'#' sign represents the id of a html element. it is for:

```
<div id='main'>...</div>
```

'.' sign  represents the class of a html element. and this is for:

```
<div class='main'>...</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

From [the HTML 4 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#id-and-class):

> The id attribute assigns a **unique** identifier to an element.
>
> The id attribute has several roles in HTML:
>
> - As a style sheet selector.
> - As a target anchor for hypertext links.
> - As a means to reference a particular element from a script.
> - As the name of a declared OBJECT element.
> - For general purpose processing by
>     user agents (e.g. for identifying
>     fields when extracting data from HTML
>     pages into a database, translating
>     HTML documents into other formats,
>     etc.).
>
> The class attribute, on the other hand, assigns one or more class names to an element; the element may be said to belong to these classes. A class name may be shared by several element instances. The class attribute has several roles in HTML:
>
> - As a style sheet selector (when an author wishes to assign style
>     information to a set of elements).
> - For general purpose processing by user agents.

Answer (score 5):

A class (.my_class_name) may be present multiple times in the same page while an id (#my_id_name) is unique.

Answer (score 1):

'#' represents using a id, and . represents an class. As you are aware, you can't duplicate IDs in HTML, so if you want the same styling to represent multiple items, you'd use a class instead.

Answer (score 1):

# is applied automatically to element with same id
CSS

```
#id1 {some style}
```

HTML

```
<div id="id1"> <-- automatically applied here...
```

CSS

```
.Dot1 {}
DIV.Dot2 {}
```

DIV.Dot2 an only be applied to DIV with class "Dot2" if any other element tries to use Dot2 it will not work

HTML

```
<div class="Dot1"> <-- only applies when you give class..
```

. is not applied automatically indeed you have to use it in "class" attribute of every element where you want to apply them.

Answer (score 1):

The `#` indicates an [ID selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#id-selectors), the `.` a [class selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#class-html). [IDs must be unique in a document](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#adef-id) (so there is only one element with one specific ID) while a [class](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#adef-class)  can contain multiple elements and an element can be in multiple classes.

So `#main` will select *the one* element that’s ID `main` is while `.main` will select *all* elements that are in the class `main`. Apart from that, both selectors have a different [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity) that affect the order in which CSS properties are applied to elements or overwrite existing properties.

Answer (score 0):

`#` used with an id name for writing css for it in a html page that must be unique.

`.` used with a class name for writing css for it that can used anywhere in html page.

**Example::**

```
 <div id="container"> 
     <div class="container"> 
        <div class="container"> 
             Foo thing
        </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

And its CSS as below

```
#container, .container {
   position: relative;
   margin: 20px 50px;
   ......
   .........
}
```

or seperate as below

```
#container {
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px 50px;
    ......
    .........
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px 50px;
    ......
    .........
}
```